# Todo list with Laravel and Vue.js v-model problem

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I made a todolist with Laravel and Vue.js: I can add a category and for every category I can add a list of todos. For every category list, there is an input to add a new todo for the category.

I made everything with one component. I created the api with Laravel.

Everything is perfect. The only problem is: When I write something in the input "add a todo", it also write in the other inputs. It's logic because there is v-model directive in the input tag.

Is it possible to bypass this behaviour ?

The content of the vue component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <form @submit.prevent="addCategorie()">
        <!-- Grid row -->
        <div class="form-row align-items-center" style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-auto">
                <!-- Default input -->
                <input v-model="categorie.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Categorie">
            </div>
            <!-- Grid column -->

            <!-- Grid column -->
            <div class="col-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md mt-0">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Grid row -->
    </form>
     <div class="row">
        <section v-for="(categorie) in categories" v-bind:key="categorie.id" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 2rem;">
                    <div class="card-header align-items-center">
                        <h3>{{ categorie.name }}
                            <span @click="deleteCategorie(categorie.id)"  style="font-size: 24px; color: #FF3547;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                        </h3>
                        <input  v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo(categorie.id)" v-model="todo.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Add a todo">
                    </div>
                    <ul v-for="todo in categorie.todos" v-bind:key="todo.id" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            {{ todo.name }}
                            <span @click="deleteTodo(todo.id)"  style="font-size: 14px; color: #FF3547;">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            categories: [],
            categorie: {
                id: '',
                name: ''
            },
            categorie_id: '',
            todos: [],
            todo: {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                categorie_id: '',
                check: ''
            },
            todo_id: ''
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchTodos();
        this.fetchCategories();
    },

    methods: {
        fetchTodos() {
            fetch('api/todos')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.categories = res.data
            })
        },
        fetchCategories() {
            fetch('api/categories')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.categories = res.data
            })
        },
        deleteCategorie(id) {
           if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
                fetch(`api/categorie/${id}`, {
                    method: 'delete'
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.fetchCategories()
                    this.fetchTodos()
                })
                .catch(err => alert(err))
           }
        },
        deleteTodo(id) {
           if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
                fetch(`api/todo/${id}`, {
                    method: 'delete'
                })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.fetchTodos()
                })
                .catch(err => alert(err))
           }
        },
        addCategorie() {
            fetch('api/categorie', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.categorie),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.clearForm();
                this.fetchCategories();
                this.fetchTodos();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
        addTodo(categorie_id) {
            // Add
            fetch(`api/todo/${categorie_id}`, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.todo),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.clearForm();
                this.fetchTodos();
                this.fetchCategories();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
        clearForm() {
            this.todo.name = '';
            this.categorie.name = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me
Thanks you very much and have a nice week-end

best regards,

Cyril

Comment: your `v-model="todo.name"` refers to the single `todo.name` in your data, so of course they're all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find an other solution
I get the value from input and I pass the param to the api url

The code:

Input in the template:

```
<input  v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo(categorie.id)" type="text" class="form-control" v-bind:id="categorie.id" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Add a todo">
```

function: addTodo()

```
addTodo(categorie_id) {
            let val = document.getElementById(categorie_id).value
            fetch(`api/todo/${categorie_id}/${val}`, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.todo),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.clearInput(categorie_id);
                this.fetchTodos();
                this.fetchCategories();
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
```

and the function to clear the input:

```
clearInput(categorie_id) {
            document.getElementById(categorie_id).value = '';
        }
```

Best regards,

Cyril

Answer (score 0):

You should have another property in your data to use in your input field, for example form: { name: '' } and use this one as v-model on your input v-model="form.name"

Comment: Hello Marian thanks you for your answer but I don't really undersand. If I add a property and I use the property in my v-model I have the same problem and the data did'nt save in the database

Comment: @Cyril, use the form object in your form input v-model only. Then use it in your addCategorie body, for example  this.form.name instead of this.categorie.